# Android: Button padding change when button state pressed

Tags: android, button

I want a to create a button that changes size (little bit smaller) when it's pressed, and after the button is released again the size should change back to normal size.

I have found an xml selector for a nice button that changes the color when its pressed.
I tried to change just the padding as you can see on the xml but it doesn't work.

Why doesn't it work? How can I do that?

I also tried to invalidate the `Button` and the `LinearLayout` which the `Button` includes when it is touched.

Layout which I inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/purplebutton"
        android:text="@string/done_button"
        android:layout_weight ="0.5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/yellowbutton"
        android:text="@string/done_button"
        android:layout_weight ="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

purplebutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#a276eb" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#6a3ab2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#a276eb"
                android:endColor="#6a3ab2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#6a3ab2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding actually gives the specified space inside the button. So it will not change size of the button always. Better specify different width and height for normal and pressed states.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

put "button_selector.xml" under "drawable" folder
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonhoverimage" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonhoverimage" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonnormalimage" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonhoverimage" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>

try to use button selector this way
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do it programatically,  ...

```
mControls.UpButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(context);
                        Button b = new Button(context);
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                        params.setMargins(top, left, bottom, right);
                       fl.addView(b,params);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(context);
                        Button b = new Button(context);
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                        params.setMargins(top, left, bottom, right);
                        fl.addView(b,params);
                    break;
                }
                return false;

            }           
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want :-

```
Your_Button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Your_Button,
                            "scaleX", 0.8f);
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Your_Button,
                            "scaleY", 0.8f);
                    scaleDownX.setDuration(1000);
                    scaleDownY.setDuration(1000);

                    AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
                    scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);

                    scaleDown.start();


                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            Your_Button, "scaleX", 1f);
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            Your_Button, "scaleY", 1f);
                    scaleDownX2.setDuration(1000);
                    scaleDownY2.setDuration(1000);

                    AnimatorSet scaleDown2 = new AnimatorSet();
                    scaleDown2.play(scaleDownX2).with(scaleDownY2);

                    scaleDown2.start();


                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

here what you need to do in xml :-

```html
<Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"
        android:background="@drawable/yellowbutton"
        android:text="@string/done_button"
        android:layout_weight ="0.5"/>
```

make use of **scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY)**,it will keep the animated position and will not restore it back to original

Hope it solves your problem cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the method onClick of your Button, you can change the padding and what ever you want programmatically with Buttons methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size or padding by xml selector, You can do this by java code on onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for resize button.

But in my linearLayout i have 2 such buttons and every time i press one the linearLayout calculates the other buttons width. That means also the other button changing the size a little bit. looks very strange.

What i want is that i have two buttons next to each other and when i press on just that one should change the size when its pressed.

Any ideas?

Here how i set the padding:

```
int size1 = btnLayout.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
    if (btnLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof View) {
            final Button mybutton1;
            final Button mybutton2;
            View myView = btnLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (myView.getId() == id.cancel_button) {
                // cancel button
                mybutton1 = (Button)  btnLayout.getChildAt(i);
                mybutton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        int action = event.getAction();
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            mybutton1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            mybutton1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            } else if (myView.getId() == id.done_button) {
                // done button
                mybutton2 = (Button)  btnLayout.getChildAt(i);
                mybutton2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        int action = event.getAction();

                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            mybutton2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            mybutton2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            }
    }   



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:variablePadding [as described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Boolean. "true" if the drawable's padding should change based on the current state that is selected; "false" if the padding should stay the same (based on the maximum padding of all the states). Enabling this feature requires that you deal with performing layout when the state changes, which is often not supported. Default is false.